# Javascript Simple Inheritance method

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Im new to oo concepts using javascript. 
From [ejohn.org](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) simple-inheritance

Standard Prototypal Inheritance

```
function Person(){}
function Ninja(){}
Ninja.prototype = new Person();
// Allows for instanceof to work:
(new Ninja()) instanceof Person
```

Statement from website over the above

> What's challenging about this, though, is that all we really want is
>   the benefits of 'instanceof', not the whole cost of instantiating a
>   Person object and running its constructor. To counteract this we have
>   a variable in our code, initializing, that is set to true whenever we
>   want to instantiate a class with the sole purpose of using it for a
>   prototype.

What does the above statement mean?

What are all the advantages of simple-inheritance by john-resig over standard prototypal inheritance?

```
var fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/
```

What is this above test for?

Can anyone explain the flow of the self-executing function? Although the code is annotated I couldn't follow the flow

Answer (score 2):

It means, we can instantiate a class to use `instanceof` without having to invoke its faux constructor function `init`.

[Fred](http://sustainablecode.com/blog) [provides an answer](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/#comment-299653) to your second query...

> The xyz test determines whether the browser can inspect the textual
>   body of a function. If it can, you can perform an optimization by only
>   wrapping an overridden method if it actually calls this._super()
>   somewhere in its body. Since it requires an additional closure and
>   function call overhead to support _super, it’s nice to skip that step
>   if it isn’t needed.